# Python arabic text in kv language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have already tried the location to the font thing, like this:

```
   Label:
        font_name: 'Titr.ttf'


        font_size: 34


        text: "پاسمار"
```

i used b titr, i renamed b titr to titr, it does find it as the ttf is in the same folder, i can see the differences, when there isn't font_name: 'Titr.ttf', it gives out a bunch of random things, but when the titr is there, its only vertical rectangles.

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/python  -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from functools import partial
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import sys
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
import random
import time
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

import time
import threading



class ScreensApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return RootWidget()


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenTwo, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):  
    def on_press(self):
        print ('pressed')

    def displayScreenThenLeave(self):
        self.changeScreen()

    def changeScreen(self):
        if self.manager.current == 'screen1':
            self.manager.current = 'screen2'
        else:
            self.manager.current = 'screen1'


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=NoTransition())
        return m

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
class The_AssignmentApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return RootWidget()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    The_AssignmentApp().run()









#:kivy 1.10.1
```

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
<ScreenOne>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.size
        spacing: 15                
        padding: 200


    Label:
        font_name: 'Titr.ttf'
        font_size: 34
        text: "پاسمار"
    Button:
        background_color: 0, 255, 0, .255
        text: "Start Pasmar"
        on_release: root.manager.current = "screen2"

<ScreenTwo>:

    BoxLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"
    size: root.size
    spacing: 20
    padding: 20
    ImageButton:
        Image:
            source:'Card_club.png'  
            size_hint: .2, .2


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: "screen1"
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "screen2"
        manager: screen_manager
```